# Doctrine cache problem on windows when doing multiple request at once

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I am using symfony 4 with doctrine ORM to build an SPA.

On initial load of the SPA, the page do between 5 and 6 request to load initial parameters. However, on windows, approximately 20% of the time I get a doctrine cache error :

```
Warning: rename(C:\Users\ZRTW9851\Documents\projects\PHP Tools\var\cache\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__AppEntityUpr.php.5eb16c31c580f1.02128983,C:\Users\ZRTW9851\Documents\projects\PHP Tools\var\cache\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__AppEntityUpr.php): Access denied. (code: 5) (500 Internal Server Error)
```

I have multiple questions :

- Is it a bad design to do multiple request at once on the client side ?
- How can I solve the cache problem given that I am using windows ?
- Do I have to show some code for this problem ? This problem occur randomly and not on specific endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

A Webserver should be able to handle multiple requests. Due to having a "Permission denied" it looks more that the File or Dir could not be renamed due to access restrictions.

This could occur due to many problems:

- Dir ist not writable -> [How to check on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/364083/windows-list-files-and-their-permissions-access-in-command-line)
- The Space " " for "PHP Tools" could be a problem -> try to rename to "PHP_Tools"
- If you're using some kind of VM or Docker it could be a problem there or with mounting that folder